# Passing value via useContext results in undefined value in consuming component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context

I am trying to set up `useContext` in my react native app to make some data universally available, but something in my set up is wrong, as the value I'm passing down ends up being `undefined` in a component I'm trying to consume the data in.

First off, I have this - notice I am passing `245` down as a test:

```
import React from 'react';

const DataContext = React.createContext();

export const DataProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return <DataContext.Provider value={245}>{children}</DataContext.Provider>;
};
```

Then I wrap my `App.js` file in that provider like so:

```
import Navigator from './src/navigation/Navigator';
import { DataProvider } from './src/context/DataContext';

export default App = (props) => {
  return (
    <DataProvider>
      <Navigator />
    </DataProvider>
  );
};
```

And then in the component down the tree I try to consume it like so

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-virtualized-view';
import { getShortTeamName } from './../utils';
import TOP_GOAL_SCORERS from '../data/goalScorers';
import { DataProvider } from '../context/DataContext';

const Item = ({ name, team, goals, value }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.name}>{name}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.team} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Team')}>
      {team}
    </Text>
    <Text style={styles.goals}>{goals}</Text>
  </View>
);

const GoalScorersScreen = () => {
  const value = useContext(DataProvider);
  console.log('value 20: ', value); // this is undefined
  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={TOP_GOAL_SCORERS}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Item name={item.name} value={value} goals={item.goals} team={getShortTeamName(item.team)} />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
      />
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

What am I missing with this setup/implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass your created context into the `useContext` hook, not the `DataProvider`

```
import { DataContext } from '../context/DataContext';
...

const GoalScorersScreen = () => {
  const value = useContext(DataContext);
  ...
};
```

Comment: No, you're passing the `DataProvider` component to the `useContext` hook with `const value = useContext(DataProvider);`.

Comment: I've created a simplified prototype of your code here https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-browser-gk0qr1?file=/src/App.js. Please take a look at it to check if you missed anything.

Comment: Thanks, had a syntax error to fix on my end, but this is correct!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you export the context object(DataContext in this case):

```
import React from 'react';

export const DataContext = React.createContext();

export const DataProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return <DataContext.Provider value={245}>{children}</DataContext.Provider>;
};
```

And then pass DataContext to useContext instead of DataProvider:

```
  const value = useContext(DataContext);
```

After that, it should work for you.